# Poynting Vector Volume Integral Inside a Cavity

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, momentum, classical-electrodynamics, poynting-vector

Given an electromagnetic wave in resonance mode in a vacuum cavity inside a perfect conductor, on the boundary, the parallel component of $E$ field vanishes, and the perpendicular of component of $B$ field vanishes. How does one derive, through solving Maxwell equation boundary value problem, say by the way of stress-energy tensor or other by products of the Maxwell equation, $\frac{\partial \int_{\text{cavity}}\mathbf S dV}{\partial t} = 0$ or $\frac{\partial \int_{\text{cavity}} \mathbf<S>dV}{\partial t} = 0$ where $\mathbf S=E\times B$ is the Poynting vector, the integral is over the space of the cavity, $<\cdot>$ denotes time average? In other words, how does one show the total momentum of the field inside the cavity vanishes from Maxwell equation computation?